# binding click to function in array in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to bind a click function from an array, but it doesn't seem to work.

I made a simple example below.

How do I make it work?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    itemClicked() {
      alert('item clicked')
    },
    itemClicked2() {
      alert('item clicked 2')
    },
    itemClicked3() {
      alert('item clicked 3')
    }
  },
  data: {
    list: [{
        title: "One",
        action: "itemClicked()"
      },
      {
        title: "Two",
        action: "itemClicked2()"
      },
      {
        title: "Three",
        action: "itemClicked3()"
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in list" :key="item.title">
      <button :onclick="item.action"> {{item.title}}</button>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make one function for calling you function on click.

> To use dynamic function call it is suggested to have a helper function
>   that receives the function name and call the corresponding function.

```
 <li v-for="item in list" :key="item.title">
  <button :onclick="funcioncall(item.action)"> {{item.title}}</button>
</li>


  data () {
    return {
      test: '',
      submitting: false,
       list: [{
        title: "One",
        action: "itemClicked"
      },
      {
        title: "Two",
        action: "itemClicked2"
      },
      {
        title: "Three",
        action: "itemClicked3"
      }
    ]
    }
  },
methods: {
    itemClicked() {
      alert('item clicked')
    },
    itemClicked2() {
      alert('item clicked 2')
    },
    itemClicked3() {
      alert('item clicked 3')
    },
    funcioncall(name){
      this[name]();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the actions into a common action that redirects to a specific method depending on the index.

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      methods: {
        itemClicked(index) {
          alert('item '+ index +' clicked')
        }
      },
      data: {
        list: [{
            title: "One",
            action: 1
          },
          {
            title: "Two",
            action: 2
          },
          {
            title: "Three",
            action: 3
          }
        ]
      }
    })
```

To bind an action in vuejs, you should use the below syntax:

```
<button v-on:click="itemClicked({{item.action}})">{{item.title}}</button>
     OR
<button @click="itemClicked({{item.action}})">{{item.title}}</button>
```

Comment: I think it should be `<button @click="() => itemClicked(item.action)">{{item.title}}</button>`